# How to update adobe air application after install?

Tags: php, apache-flex, air, flash

how to update air application after install in system . updated not be reinstall will be automatically ? is it possiable?

Answer (score 3):

You can ask the user of the app if they want to update... or you can program the app to be updated silently each time you want/need.

If you are looking on how to auto-update here is a nice tutorial.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/update_framework.html

Also please consult the flex help pages for more details.

**Edit**

It would appear that the link in the original answer is broken, so I have edited this answer to provide a current, working link to a tutorial for *how to check for updates to your air application and auto update*, not update the AIR runtime, as per the OP request.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air_update_framework.html

Comment: thank for response me but i want to air application (project) not AIR version . is it possiable

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I miss-understood you :)

The answer is Yes!

**Step 1.** find a way to check inside the ap if a new update is available for your application.

**Step 2.** Download the new applications version (ex app_V1.1.air)

**Step 3.** Use this code.... :D

```
import flash.fileSystem.File; 
import flash.desktop.Updater; 
var updater:Updater = new Updater(); 
var airFile:File = File.applicationStore.resolvePath("app_V1.1.air"); 
var version:String = "1.1"; 
updater.update(airFile, version);
```

For more details... consult the flex help pages and 
search for flash.desktop.Updater

---

Adrian